# Is there a way to get better format with Dr Racket / racket failed test case message?

Tags: racket

When I run my tests in Dr. Racket or from the command line, a failed test is always on one line.

For example,

```
(bad (interp-t-prog (list '(class posn extends object ((x : num) (y : num)) (mdist : num -> num (+ (get this x) (get this y))) (addDist : posn -> num (+ (send arg mdist 0) (send this mdist 0)))) '(class posn3D extends posn ((z : num)) (mdist : num -> num (+ (get this z) (super mdist arg))))) `this) -1 "no type" "at line 96")
```

Is there a way to get the message to be formatted better besides manually entering white space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the error produced by your code or a Racket library?

Would [`pretty-print`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pretty-print.html?q=pretty-print#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpretty..rkt%29._pretty-print%29%29) help you?

```
#lang racket
(pretty-print
 '(bad (interp-t-prog (list '(class posn extends object ((x : num) (y : num)) (mdist : num -> num (+ (get this x) (get this y))) (addDist : posn -> num (+ (send arg mdist 0) (send this mdist 0)))) '(class posn3D extends posn ((z : num)) (mdist : num -> num (+ (get this z) (super mdist arg))))) `this) -1 "no type" "at line 96"))
```

=>

```
'(bad
  (interp-t-prog
   (list
    '(class posn
       extends
       object
       ((x : num) (y : num))
       (mdist : num -> num (+ (get this x) (get this y)))
       (addDist : posn -> num (+ (send arg mdist 0) (send this mdist 0))))
    '(class posn3D
       extends
       posn
       ((z : num))
       (mdist : num -> num (+ (get this z) (super mdist arg)))))
   `this)
  -1
  "no type"
  "at line 96")
```

Comment: The error is from my code. pretty-print looks promising, but how can I use it? Do I just write a separate script to read in my test error message and append the single quote mark and pretty-print?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more code. How is your error message generated?

Comment: The errors are printed to stderr. I edited your solution to include what I used to get pretty-print to work for me.

Comment: Oh, I was more asking if you had access to the Racket code that generates the error. Something like `(eprintf "~a\n" (mk-err-msg))` or `(error 'bad "~a\n" (mk-err-msg))` where you replace `(mk-err-msg)` with `(pretty-print (mk-err-msg))`.

Comment: I'm actually using plai-typed which is heavily based off of racket, and I'm using plai-typed's test function which generates the error. Pretty-print isn't included in plai-typed so I'm not sure how I could use it in my plai-typed program file.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not familiar with `plai-typed` but I'm not seeing a `require` form in the docs, so your solution is probably the best you can do. You can also submit a bug report though. I would guess either the plai github issues or the racket mailing list (users@racket-lang.org) would be your best chance at a response.

Comment: Looking into it some more, it looks like `plai-typed` is based on [`plai`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plai/plai-scheme.html?q=plai&q=plai), so maybe submit a bug report against that. Or submit a pull request :) Maybe in [`print-error`](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/master/pkgs/plai/test-harness.rkt)?

Comment: The source code for plai-typed is here [link](https://github.com/mflatt/plai-typed/blob/master/plai-typed/main.rkt). Since it requires `racket/pretty` already, providing pretty-print and related functionality within the language should be reasonably straight forward.